# Flutter: json_serializable 1 => true, 0 => false

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization

I'm using json_serializable for parsing `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` to my object.
Example:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Todo {
  String title;
  bool done;

  Todo(this.title, this.done);

  factory Todo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$TodoFromJson(json);
}
```

Because I'm getting `'done': 1` from the api, I get following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'bool' in type cast
```

How can I cast `1 = true` and `0 = false` with json_serializable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can have custom converter (in this example it's `int` to `Duration` thanks to the method `_durationFromMilliseconds`) :

https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/blob/master/example/lib/example.dart

So in your code it might be something like this :

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Todo {
  String title;

  @JsonKey(fromJson: _boolFromInt, toJson: _boolToInt)
  bool done;

  static bool _boolFromInt(int done) => done == 1;

  static int _boolToInt(bool done) => done ? 1 : 0;

  Todo(this.title, this.done);

  factory Todo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$TodoFromJson(json);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved me! That's what I was looking for!